# How to set permalink to fetch all children custom posts with parent post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I create parent-child relationship for custom posts types.

> Generic : www.example.com/parent/parent_post
>
> Sample  : www.example.com/projects/project-one

In above URL parent is a custom post type and parent post is its single post.
I can show parents all posts and single post respectively as archive-parent.php and single-parent.php .

As I mentioned earlier, I create parent-child relationship and with child post that stores 'post_parent' as parent id.

> Generic : www.example.com/child/parent_post/child_post
>
> Sample  :
>   www.example.com/project_article/project-one/first-article

And for specific child post, URL will be as above.

Below code is for to get specific child post.And it's working fine.

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%child%', '([^/]+)', 'child=');
    add_permastruct('child', 'child/%parent%/%child%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?child=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );

function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'child' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
    $permalink = str_replace('%parent%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

> Generic : www.example.com/child/parent_post
>
> Sample  : www.example.com/project_article/project-one

Now I want all child posts with parent post, as in above URL.

I am new to word-press Please guide.

Comment: Your local server links won't work here.

Comment: You can't post localhost links here.

Comment: Little bit confused - are you having a single custom post type named `child` with parent-child hierarchy and you want to list all the child posts when accessed a parent page?

Comment: yes you almost got my question @OutsourceWordPress i want all child post related to single parent and i am storing parent_post(id) in child post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `parent` as parent custom post type, `child` as child custom post type and hope you need child posts URL like `http://www.example.com/parent/parent-post/child/child-post` instead of `http://www.example.com/child/parent-post/child-post`.

Change your `my_add_rewrite_rules()` function to the following.

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%child%', '([^/]+)', 'child=');
    add_permastruct('child', '/parent/%parent%/child/%child%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^parent/([^/]+)/child/([^/]+)/?','index.php?child=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

After updating don't forgot to **flush permalinks** via 'Settings > Permalinks'.

Comment: i had already make {single-custom-post-type-name}.php, if you see this URL : Sample : www.example.com/project_article/project-one/first-article and code : add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?child=$matches[2]','top'); please read my question again thanks in advance and if you look at this url https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/ you can get single child post related to single parent and can't get all children post related to single parent.

Comment: Oh, are you using 2 custom post types and link second post type posts as child of first post type?

Comment: Where are you saying all child posts are not listing - in the 'parent' meta box?

Comment: look into this URL : Sample : www.example.com/project_article/project-one/first-article. project-one is parent custom post type single post and first-article is child of project-one of custom post type single post.project-one post have multiple child posts now i want if i use URL : www.example.com/project_article/project-one then fetch all child posts related to project-one custom post

Comment: if i add single-parent.php then it will return all the posts related to parent post type not it's child.

Comment: Can you try my updated answer - you need to change your child custom post type name in post_type argument? It will show all the child post titles with its URL in front-end parent parent page.

Comment: if i follow your solution it will show child posts for parent but then what about single page for parent type post.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about your requirement. If you follow my answer, it will list all the child posts mapped to the particular parent in the parent single page. Are you referring something different? Can you explain little bit detail?

Comment: Do you want to change the child posts URL here instead (not to display the posts in the content)?

Comment: I misunderstood your question completely and now I understand by reading your initial question before edit. Look out my updated answer and let me know whether it works.